# Is xml in web-terms different from xml in android-terms

Tags: android, xml, web

So I was doing a google search on xml, and most of the links were about xml in web-terms. One of the [websites](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp) state:

> XML does not DO anything. XML was created to structure, store, and transport information.

In android ( I'm a newbie ), there are these .xml files that hold the UI design of an app.

So, what xml exactly is? Is it a language for UI designing, information transport/storage, or both?

Answer (score 0):

XML in Android does not do anything either. But the Android SDK and Android OS would **interpret** those XML files and, based on their contents, build an UI, define animations etc.

An example from the Android world would be the layout file. It contains **information** such as what elements will be displayed on the screen, what would be their position, colors etc. But those documents won't "show the UI" on the screen. Instead, Android runtime will read them, interpret their contents and finally use that information to create interface elements.

So you can see that the meaning XML documents have depends on the application. To help with that, often the XSD (XML Schema Defintion) or DTD (Document Type Defintion) is created. Those special documents describe the structure the XML document can have for the given application. It is not necessary to have them, though.